# How do I fit the border to the LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, xml, border, android-linearlayout

how do I fit the border exactly to its contents (through xml)
here's my border:

```
  <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
            <stroke android:color="#000000" android:width="2dp"/>
            <padding android:top="100dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
```

and my layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingTop="25dp">
```

here's a picture: [image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to implement RecyclerView and your layout is the ViewHolder.xml for the element.

I would suggest setting the viewHolder's width to `match_parent`and height to `wrap_content` instead of specifying fixed pixel values to achieve what you want.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingTop="25dp">
```

I would remove the padding property from your `Border` asset, rather suggest to manage the spacing through the ViewHolders layout.

Comment: its still not working
I changed the LinearLayout like you said and removed the padding
but its still remained the same

Comment: Can you add an image to see what changed please.

Comment: No worries, i Would suggest to edit your post by including how you fixed it.